# Тонкости использования пользовательских функций удаления со стандартными умными указателями

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, shared-ptr, удаление

Я пытаюсь использовать возможности стандартных умных указателей по заданию пользовательских функций (политик) удаления. У меня есть два вопроса.

1. Могу ли я задать для `std::unique_ptr` и `std::shared_ptr` пользовательскую функцию удаления без указания в списке параметров шаблона конкретного типа функции удаления?

   Например, у меня не получается сделать так:

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<int> ui{ new int(), [](int*){ ... } };
   ```

   Но получается так:

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)>> ui{ new int(), [](int*){ ... } };
   ```

   Я не совсем понимаю, почему так.
2. Будет ли копироваться/перемещаться заданная функция удаления при копировании/перемещении соответствующего умного указателя? Всегда ли это будет происходить, или есть исключения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

М. Скотт - Эффективный и современный C++ 11-14 (гл. 4.3):

> Подобно std::unique_ptr, std::shared_ptr в качестве механизма удаления ресурса по умолчанию использует delete, но подерживает и пользовательские удалители. Однако дизайн этой поддержки отличается от дизайна для std::unique_ptr. Для std::unique_ptr тип удалителя является частью типа интеллектуального указателя. Для std::shared_ptr это не так:
>
> ```cpp
> auto loggingDel = [] (Widget *pw) // Пользовательскй удалитель
> {
>    makeLogEntry(pw);
>    delete pw;
> };
>
> std::unique_ptr<                  // Тип удалителя является
>     Widget, decltype(loggingDel)  // частью типа указателя
>     > upw (new Widget, loggingDel);
>
> std::shared_ptr<Widget>             // Тип удалителя не является
>     spw (new Widget, loggingDel);   // частью типа указателя
> ```

Т.к. `shared_ptr` с разными удалителями являются объектами одного и того же типа, то они могут быть помещены в один и тот же контейнер, присвоены один другому и т.п. С `unique_ptr` такое не выйдет, т.к. тип удалителя является частью типа самого `unique_ptr`.

Следовательно:

1. Для `unique_ptr` тип пользовательской функции удаления нужно явно задать через параметр шаблона `unique_ptr`, либо воспользоваться автоматическим выведением типа, а для `shared_ptr` это всегда вызываемый объект с параметром `T*`.

---

Что касается второго вопроса.  Для `unique_ptr` пользовательский удалитель хранится в виде указателя на функцию или функционального объекта (заданного через параметр шаблона). Для `shared_ptr` пользовательский удалитель (как и счетчик ссылок, слабый счеткик, аллокатор и т.п.) является частью управляющего блока, выделенного в динамической памяти.

Поэтому:

2. При копировании/перемещении умного указателя функция не копируется/перемещается. Копирование/перемещение умного указателя копирует/перемещает только указатель на эту функцию(функц. объект) или на управляющий блок.